# Open-source replacement of Intel Image Processing library

Tags: image-processing, fractals

Is there any open-source library to replace proprietary Intel Image Processing Library? At first I need to do image loading-saving, filtering (3x3,5x5 and so) with arbitrary kernel. Support of manychannel images with pixel values stored as float will be wonderful. Also I need a library with good documentation.

PS. both linux/x86 & windows/x86. I want to use it with mingw32 on windows.

PPS. The first task I need to solve using this library is to compute an fractal dimension.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/) is probably what you're looking for.
The latest version (2.2) contains both SSE optimization *a-la* IPP and CUDA implementations.

Answer (score 3):

There is [opencv](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/)

If you want to go Cuda then the [Nvidia Performance Primitives](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/npp_home.html)